# Display records based on availability of two conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have following table in my database:

```
Invoice_no  Type  Amount
------------------------
INV001      ET101  4000
INV001      ET102  4000
INV002      ET101  3400
INV002      ET102  3400
INV003      ET101  2300
```

I want to display those rows of invoice numbers only which have both `ET101` and `ET102` type. Any invoice number which do not have both entry type will not be displayed. Please suggest best way to do that using a query in SQL Server.

Result after suggested query will be:

```
Invoice_no  Type  Amount
------------------------
INV001      ET101  4000
INV001      ET102  4000
INV002      ET101  3400
INV002      ET102  3400
```

`INV003` only has `ET101`, so it will not be displayed.

Comment: Let's say there was an imaginary `ET103` type, and `INV001` has it. Should `INV001` records still be displayed, or would that disqualify them? If they should be displayed, what about that specific `ET103` record? Should it also be displayed, or would it be filtered? This can change what the answer looks like.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn No there can not be the 3rd type.From the client end only these two types are fixed- ET101,ET102. Any other type will never be included.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tbl(Invoice_no,  Type,  Amount)


select *
from tbl a
where a.Type  = 'ET101'
and exists (
  select 1
  from tbl b
  where b.Type  = 'ET102' and a.Invoice_no = b.Invoice_no
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query

```
SELECT *
FROM Invoice
WHERE Invoice_no IN (
  SELECT distinct INVOICE_NO FROM Invoice
  WHERE TYPE = 'ET101'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT distinct INVOICE_NO FROM Invoice
  WHERE TYPE = 'ET102'
)
```

Comment: When using `IN` you don't need the `DISTINCT` and its probably faster not to have it. PS as a new contributor can you please learn how to format code.

Comment: Agreed with @Dale K. Thanks for your effort sumeet.It matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both *rows*, then I might suggest:

```
select i.*
from invoice i
where (i.type = 'ET101' and
       exists (select 1
               from invoice i2
               where i2.invoice_no = i.invoice_no and
                     i2.type = 'ET102'
              )
      ) or
      (i.type = 'ET102' and
       exists (select 1
               from invoice i2
               where i2.invoice_no = i.invoice_no and
                     i2.type = 'ET101'
              )
      ) ;
```

You can actually shorten this logic to:

```
select i.*
from invoice i
where i.type in ('ET101', 'ET102') and
      exists (select 1
              from invoice i2
              where i2.invoice_no = i.invoice_no and
                    i2.type in ('ET101', 'ET102') and
                    i2.type <> i.type
              );
```

If you only wanted the invoice numbers, then I would suggest aggregation:

```
select i.invoice_no
from invoice i
where i.type in ('ET101', 'ET102') 
group by i.invoice_no
having count(distinct i.type) = 2;
```